# Why won't the spacing between uicollectionviewcells equal to 0?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/lukagabric/LGLinearFlow) and I've tried messaging the library creator but to no avail. I've tried playing around with/changing lots of the code, however I'm having no luck in fully understanding what's taking place.

The problem: I am having problems making the spacing between the cells equal 0; for some odd reason when I set the collectionview item size to the screen width minus 30, there is still a huge gap between the cells despite me setting the minimumspacing to 0. Basically, the next cells, whose edges should be on screen, are not. I want them to be hugging each other practically, but it seems that each cell is centered and the spacing between the cells is the screensize - cell item size. Further, when I scroll through occasionally, next cell is hugging, and then immediately gets reset once it comes on screen. When I change the width of the cell to something a lot smaller, the spacing between them only grows.

I've tried commenting out offset / inset lines of code, but those only ruin the effect and don't actually make any change to the cell spacing. I've also tried to manipulate the values of the offset / inset. The only "solution" i've created is to use a negative value for the minimumlinespacing, but that only exacerbates the hugging glitch that occurs and makes the reset visibly drastic.

Any pointers?

Comment: Did u use LGHorizontalLinearFlowLayout as the UICollectionViewLayout?
Have you set the width and height of ur cell correctly so that there is no extra spacing?

Comment: @nerezza yes, during the xibsetup, i set it up like this: 'collectionViewLayout = HorizontalLinearFlowLayout.configureLayout(collectionView: self.collectionView, itemSize: self.constraints.itemSize, minimumLineSpacing: self.constraints.minimumageSpacing)' I have a struct that has cell sizes for each phone size